# Using sed to return value after '='

Tags: unix, sed, awk

been reading up on the sed command in Unix and I think it will do what I want it to, just not sure on its crazy syntax.

Basically, I want to get just the value inside brackets after Count= in the last line of a file.  So, in the line there will be a `Count=[#]` and I want just the # to be returned.  Any thoughts? Is sed even the best choice (heard awk might do something similar)?

Comment: @KeithThompson Sorry, editied. Hope its more clear

Comment: Sed's syntax is no crazier than that of awk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A slightly different approach:

```
echo 'Count=[#]' | sed 's/.*\[\(.*\)\].*/\1/'
```

This matches the text between the `[` and `]`, and replaces the entire line with it.

Comment: Noob question, but this doesnt change the file in any way right?

Comment: The specific command I wrote doesn't read or write any file.  You can do something like `sed '...' input.txt > output.txt` to read from one file and write to another.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another approach:

```
sed -n '$ {s/Count=\[\([^]]\+\)\]/\1/;p}' yourfile
```

`-n` don't print except with `p`.

`$` for the last row.

`s/search/replace/` search will be replaced by replace.

`\([^]]\+\)` capture one or more occurrence of not ']' `^]`.

`\1` is referring to what was captured.

`p` print line.

What I can see this is the only answer taking into account that there might come Count=[#] in any row. You state that this is to happen only for the last row: ' after Count= in the last line of a file.'

Comment: This can be simplified to a single sed command; `sed -n '$s/Count=\[\([^]]\+\)\]/\1/p' yourfile` -- the `$` is an address and `/p` is available as a flag to the `s` command.

Answer (score 1):

```
kent$  echo "Count=[#]"|awk -F'[][]' '{print $2}'
#


kent$  echo "Count=[#]"|sed -r 's/.*\[(.*)\].*/\1/'
#
```

Comment: Well, `grep Count filename.log | tail -1 | awk -F'Count=[][]' '{print $2}'` returned `0]` which is super close... how do I get rid of that trailing ']'?

Comment: what's the output of `grep Count filename.log | tail -1`

Comment: The general structure of the output is `2011-10-20 08:43:36.051 TibrvConnectivity Lots of stuff Count=[0]`... Also I totally forgot that I need to grab that date and time too (so the result of the command in the above case should be `2011-10-20 08:43:36.051 0`.  I tried `... | sed 's/\(.*\)Tib.*/\1/'` and that seemed to work fine to get the date, but I cant find a way to combine the two

Answer (score 0):

With sed, just use a couple of regular expressions to remove the part you don't want:

```
sed -e 's/^Count=\[//' -e 's/\]$//' < file.txt
```

or

```
sed 's/^Count=\[//;s/\]$//' < file.txt
```

The first expression will remove `Count=[` and the second expression will remove the trailing `]`.

Comment: I tried `sed -e 's/^Count=[//' -e 's/]$//' filename.log | tail -1` and it said `sed: Function s/^Qcnt=[// cannot be parsed.`

Comment: Did you enter ctrl+c or the characters ^ and C? In this case, you want to use the characters, not the control sequence.

Comment: Im sorry, Im pretty new to unix and Im not sure what you mean

Comment: @Hershizer33: There was an error in the answer. `sed` uses `[` and `]` as special characters to specify ranges of characters (for example, `[0-9]` matches any digit); you need to escape them with `\` characters.  I've edited the answer.